# calling method in one jsp from another jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am completely new to jsp, and I have been stuck on this for quite a while.

I am developing a jsp page, a.jsp, in which I need to do some checking on a parameter x obtained from request.getHeader(). The method for checking is already written on b.jsp in <%...%> tags and I would like to somehow call that method on a.jsp.

I'm not sure what I can do here since I am not suppose to change b.jsp, just redevelop a.jsp. Is there any way I can call a method from b.jsp in a.jsp?

Comment: Write your java code in `Java` classes, and call them from any jsp. Scriptlets are so antiquated, that their border _taboo_

Answer (score 1):

Include the b.jsp into the a.jsp and you can access all your methods.

```
<%@ include file="a.jsp"%>
```

Comment: what would the syntax be to call the method, for example chk(var x), in a.jsp?

Comment: also, does this still work if b.jsp is on a different server than a.jsp?

Comment: u mean how to call method ? suppose void chk(int a) { /*do something ..*/} in a.jsp than call it as  chk(10); in b.jsp !!  But it won't work if they are in different server, its need to be exists in same path during running.

Comment: I will suggest if u have some utility kind of methods write it in java and create jar file and import those classes in jsp <%@page import="package name"%> so u can use those methods in a.jsp and b.jsp with common base code (jar). And can keep a.jsp + jar in one server and jar+b.jsp in another.